# How to trigger compaction in Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I create topic with this settings:

```
    final AdminClient localKafkaAdmin = AdminClient.create(consumerProps);
    final NewTopic topic = new NewTopic("test-v1", 1, (short) 1);

    Map<String, String> topicConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
    topicConfigMap.put(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_COMPACT);
    topicConfigMap.put(TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG, "2");
    topic.configs(topicConfigMap);

    localKafkaAdmin.createTopics(Arrays.asList(topic));
```

after that send 3 messages with the same key via KafkaProducer. when I get ConsumerRecords I see that compaction wasn't applied, there are 3 records. What am I doing wrong? tried with segment.bytes setting but got the same result. how to trigger compaction immediately?

Comment: I don't think that settings delete.retention.ms and retention.bytes can help here. they are used with another retention policy(delete)

Comment: Immediate compaction is not recommended, for obvious reasons of CPU load on the broker... If you want to build a lookup table of latest key to values, use Kafka Streams to make a KTable. Don't require the broker to do that for you

Comment: this is just for integration test, only for checking. thanks anyway

Comment: regarding to your comment about using Kafka Streams - unfortunately my task is not good for using streams. using streams means continuous consuming from Kafka, but I need to read all existing messages and close consumer. I don't think using streams supposes to terminate reading and I don't know how to create condition for termination reading in this case

Comment: When there's zero lag, the stream just becomes an idle consumer. Doesn't stop you from being able to query data, but yes, requires a constant connection to the broker

Answer (score 1):

Compaction is configured by those [parameters](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/design/log_compaction.html#configure-compaction):

- log.cleanup.policy=compact
- log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms
- log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms
- min.cleanable.dirty.ratio

In your case to force compaction you probably want to set low value for one of the last 2. For example, log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 2. Do not forget to check both per-topic and per-broker configuration, and wait until compaction will actually be ended, since parameters only sets whether records is eligible for compaction.